# Solving an Algorithmic Challenge involving Differences between Pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

The below is an algorithmic problem I came up with, motivated by a harder problem I could not solve. Unfortunately, I cannot solve this one either.

You are given n numbers in increasing order (n is between 1 and 3*10^5, so linear running time is necessary). Each number will range from 1 to 3*10^5 as well. For each number from 1 to 3*10^5, denote this as z, you want to find how many pairs of numbers have a pairwise difference of z. Read the examples below for more clarity.

Numbers: 1,6,9
Answer: 1 pair with a difference of 5 (1,6), 1 pair with a difference of 3 (6, 9), and 1 pair with a difference of 8 (1,9)

Numbers: 1,2,3,4
Answer: 3 pairs with a difference of 1 (1,2 2,3 3,4), 2 pairs with a difference of 2 (1,3 2,4), and 1 pair with a difference of 3 (1,4).

Is there a data-structure that can be used to solve this problem in linear time?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this is easier than the other problem?

Comment: Numbers are distinct? Can they repeat after they appear once?

Comment: No, unfortunately I am not sure. Here is the other problem: http://codeforces.com/contest/386/problem/C

Comment: And yes they are distinct

Comment: @user3904846 the other problem is actually much easier.

Comment: @user3904846 The problem you linked does not ask you to compute the pair-wise differences.

Comment: Yes I just realized that after realizing that the diversity can be at most 26 :\. oops. Still, I would like to know if there are any data structures that can be used to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, but does anyone have any ideas on this problem?

Comment: @user3904846 When you say "this" problem, do you mean the problem described in your question or the other problem?

Comment: The problem described  in my question, of course. The below answer with Fast Fourier Transformation maybe hard to implement.. are there any easier datastructures like red-black tree that can be used?

Comment: @user3904846 I hate posting FFT answers on SO because that's invariably the response. If I knew of a way to get close to linear time without FFT, I would have posted that instead.

Comment: @user3904846 AFAIK, the only known (N log N) solution is Fourier Fast Transformation. It is definitely not possible to get away with something easier like binary search tree.

Comment: I was curious, so I implemented a suitable fast polynomial multiplication routine in Java. It's about 80 lines. It was much easier to debug than the red-black tree I wrote (granted, I'm a better programmer now than I was then).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an O(n polylog n)-time algorithm to compute counts for all z (assuming that we have at most n numbers between 1 and n).

Prepare two polynomials P(x) = sum_{d in the list} x^d and Q(x) = sum_{d in the list} x^(n - d). Use a fast multiplication algorithm to compute the coefficients of the polynomial product P(x) Q(x). To look up the answer for z, examine the coefficient of x^(n + z), which is

```
sum_{d in the list} sum_{e in the list} [d + n - e = n + z],
```

where [d + n - e = n + z] = [d - e = z] is 1 if d - e = z and 0 otherwise.